# Where I can find token in postman?

Tags: get, postman, token

I am struggling with one think in postman (I use it first time). I watched a course where the guy shows where token in postman can be find and we should use it. Unfortunately I can't find in place where it should be[image]

I have a free version of this program but it shouldn't be a problem. I am working on active environment

Authorization tab:
[image]

headers
[image]

body
[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots of `Body` , `Headers` and `Authorization` tab?

Comment: I added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

##### Overview

`Postman` : Want to get token and update data as client

`Server` : Provides token and update data

Token API:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/me
```

Needs `username/password`

Update Data API:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/data
```

Needs `access token`

[image]

##### How works API call from Postman

#1 User Basic Authorization

#2 Get Token API Call

#3 Response Get Token Call

#4 Save `access-token` into environment variable

#5 Update Data API Call with `access token`

[image]

##### Where is Token

From GET access token API
This is body of Response
The 'message.token` is example of access token in JSON

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "message": {
        "data": "User registered successfully",
        "token": "e9cee71ab932fde863338d08be4de9dfe39ea049bdafb342ce659ec5450b69ae"
    }
}
```

##### How to parse/save Token

In `tests` tab this script, extract the token from body response
And save it into environment variable.

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.message.token);
```

##### How to use Token

In the POST call, Bearer token type and get token value from environment variable by `{{variable_name}}`

```bash
{{access-token}}
```

##### Demo

##### Mock Server

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const crypto = require('crypto');

let accessToken; // Variable to store the access token

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS

// Get Token Endpoint
app.get('/api/me', (req, res) => {

    // Check if Authorization header is present
    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized'});
        return;
    }

    // Extract the base64 encoded credentials
    const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');

    // Check if username and password are valid
    if (username !== 'abcd' || password !== '1234') {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized'});
        return;
    }

    // Hash the token
    accessToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(username+password).digest('hex');

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: {
            data: 'User registered successfully',
            token: accessToken
        }
    });
});

// Update data API End point 
app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    const bearerToken = req.headers.authorization;

    // Check if Authorization header is present and contains Bearer token
    if (!bearerToken || bearerToken.indexOf('Bearer ') === -1) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized: Bearer token missing' });
        return;
    }

    const accessTokenFromHeader = bearerToken.split('Bearer ')[1]; // Extract the Bearer token

    // Check if the access token matches the expected value
    if (accessTokenFromHeader !== accessToken) {
        res.status(403).json({ error: 'Forbidden: Invalid access token' });
        return;
    }

    const updatedData = {
        message: "Data updated successfully",
        data: "Top Secret Data"
    };
    res.json(updatedData); // Send the updated data in JSON format
});

// Start the server
const port = 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express  cors crypto
```

##### Run server

```
node server.js
```

##### Postman call

##### Environment

[image]

##### Get access token

URL

```
GET {{baseUrl}}/api/me
```

`Tests` tab

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.message.token);
```

[image]

##### Result

[image]

##### Update Data

URL

```
POST {{baseUrl}}/api/data
```

with `access token`
[image]

##### Result

[image]

##### 401 Unauthorized Error

If I use wrong credential, will get 401 error.
Mock server only works matched user name and password.

[image]